# Как распознать блоки в зависимости от текста?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Допустим есть следующий набор элементов:

```
<br>..text..<br>
```

И CSS:

```
br+br {
 //option
}
```

Как сделать чтобы обычный текст так-же  имел свой вес и если между `<br>` тэгами есть писание хоть это и не блок - тогда CSS условие `+` не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через JavaScript это отслеживать, но таким ни кто не занимается. И вообще забудь про этот тег, если ты его используешь в верстке, значит ты что-то делаешь не так.

Comment: Забудь про забывание этого тега, если ты его не используешь его в верстке, значит ты что-то делаешь не так.

Comment: Тег, приемлем если верстаются какие-то простые сайты и вам в принципе плевать на оптимизацию, и что именно у вас храниться в БД (раз вы поленились завернуть нужный текст в span с нужным классом, или p) Если же вы, упаси бог, паритесь по поводу скорости загрузки и вам надо будет делать AMP версию вашего сайта, то вы потом будете нехорошим словом вспоминать то тело которое <br> понаставил и просто его удалити.  Вообщем, если можно не использовать, лучше - не использовать

Comment: AMP — зонд от гугла и не нужен. Мешает как разработчикам, так и пользователям, получающим кастрированную версию сайта без нормального адреса

Comment: AMP версии страниц повышаются в рейтинге выдачи Гугла. Можна сколько угодно кричать про монополию, но все ведь понимают кто диктует правила игры.

Comment: Спорно, например по запросу «python сокеты» мой сайт второй в результатах поиска, а там не то что AMP — даже просто мобильную версию сайта я не сделал, а при этом второй в результатах поиска именно на мобильнике